# Resharper navigation in CQRS pattern

Tags: c#, ide, resharper, cqrs

I am using CQRS pattern and ReSharper. Is there a way how to navigate from a query to its handler? Example from following code:

```
var query = new MyQuery();
var result = _mediator.Send(query);
```

Is there a way to easily go to MyQueryHandler implementation right from this code? Perhaps with giving cursor to the .Send() method and press some shortcut?

Comment: Try to place the cursor on the `MyQuery` and then call `ReSharper | Navigate | Navigate To | Consuming APIs` action https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigate_To_Consuming_APIs.html. Will it cover your needs?

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you @Alexander, it works like a charm!

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad to hear it helped. I've added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the cursor on the `MyQuery` and then call `ReSharper | Navigate | Navigate To | Consuming APIs` action (more info about the action is [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigate_To_Consuming_APIs.html))